# IPv6 route configuration on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: configuration, network-interface, ipv6, iproute

When I add the gateway, I got an error like this
`RTNETLINK answers: No route to host`

I used all the below commands:

```
root@server1:~# /sbin/ip -6 route add default via 2620:1e6:101::8888:1
RTNETLINK answers: No route to host
root@server1:~# ip -6 r a default via 2620:1e6:101::1/64 dev venet0
Error: an inet address is expected rather than "2620:1e6:101::1/64".
```

But the issue is not solved

Answer (score 1):

Both commands have some issues, the first one does not define an interface, while the second one indeed (as the error message says) lacks an address - `2620:1e6:101::1/64` denotes a subnet, not an address.

This should do:

```
ip -6 route add default via 2620:1e6:101::8888:1 dev venet0
```

To learn more about how to use the `ip` utility of the iproute2 suite, see the [iproute2 cheat sheet](http://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/). To delve into the depths of iproute2 magic, see [here](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html) - the document is a bit dated but still valid.